# Calling variables with string interpolation in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a variable's declaration like this;
`String user1="John"; String user2="Smith"; ....`

is there any way to call the variables in for loop;

`for(var i=1;i<3:i++) { print("${user[i]}"; }`

Comment: This is not possible without code generation.  Use a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List and get values with any loop.

```
List<String> names = ['John', 'Smith', 'Bob'];

for (var element in names) {
  print(element);
}

for (var element in names) {
  print(element);
}

for (var i = 0; i< names.length; i++) {
  print(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: The variables are retrived from the function and cannot be changed. ( function name (String user1, String user2..)

Comment: @Ali can you share the code with this function that you describe in the comment